# Pancakeswap API is down

Tags: pancakeswap

Is there an open and free alternative to using this API? It returns a 500 error right now and has been this way for a few days.

https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens

Answer (score 0):

I made a new class in C#. I hope it helps since the API is down. This gives you low level cap prices. Check the code get other idea
Sinds API pancakeswap is down and no response you have to get info other way read smart contract how they calculate prices like here
https://github.com/ArsamCodex/PanckaceSwapAPI

Test:

[image: https://imgur.com/Lbg7WjL]

```
static async Task Main(string[] args){
      
            string pancakeSwapContract = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E".ToLower();
            string tokenAddress = "0xad29abb318791d579433d831ed122afeaf29dcfe";

            Web3 web3 = new Web3("https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org");

            decimal bnbPrice =await GetBNBPriceFromAPI();
            // Console.WriteLine($"CURRENT BNB PRICE: {bnbPrice}");

            decimal tokensToSell =1;
            decimal priceInBnb = await CalcSell(web3, tokensToSell, tokenAddress, pancakeSwapContract);
            Console.WriteLine("SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN : " + priceInBnb * bnbPrice);

           // decimal tokenValueInUsd = priceInBnb * bnbPrice;
           // Console.WriteLine($"SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN USD: {tokenValueInUsd}");
        }

        private static async Task<decimal> CalcSell(Web3 web3, decimal tokensToSell, string tokenAddress, string pancakeSwapContract)
        {
            string bnbTokenAddress = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c";
            var tokenDecimals = await GetDecimals(web3, tokenAddress);

            decimal tokensToSellWithDecimals = SetDecimals(tokensToSell, tokenDecimals);

            try
            {
                var router = web3.Eth.GetContractQueryHandler<GetAmountsOutFunction>();
                var result = await router.QueryDeserializingToObjectAsync<AmountsOutDTO>(
                    new GetAmountsOutFunction
                    {
                        AmountIn = BigInteger.Parse(tokensToSellWithDecimals.ToString()),
                        Path = new List<string> { tokenAddress, bnbTokenAddress }
                    },
                    pancakeSwapContract);

                // Parse the result to extract the amountOut value
                decimal amountOutValue = Web3.Convert.FromWei(result.Amounts[1]);

                return amountOutValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred during CalcSell:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return 0;
            }
        }


        private static async Task<decimal> GetBNBPriceFromAPI()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string apiUrl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=binancecoin&vs_currencies=usd";

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    dynamic jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                    decimal bnbPrice = jsonResult["binancecoin"]["usd"];

                    return bnbPrice;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while fetching the BNB price:");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

       
        private static async Task<int> GetDecimals(Web3 web3, string tokenAddress)
        {
            var tokenRouter = web3.Eth.GetContractQueryHandler<DecimalsFunction>();
            var decimalsResult = await tokenRouter.QueryAsync<int>(tokenAddress);
            return decimalsResult;
        }

        private static decimal SetDecimals(decimal number, int decimals)
        {
            string numberString = number.ToString();
            string[] parts = numberString.Split('.');

            string numberAbs = parts[0];
            string numberDecimals = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : "";

            while (numberDecimals.Length < decimals)
            {
                numberDecimals += "0";
            }

            string resultString = numberAbs + numberDecimals;
            return decimal.Parse(resultString);
        }
    }

    [Function("getAmountsOut", "uint256[]")]
    public class GetAmountsOutFunction : FunctionMessage
    {
        [Parameter("uint256", "amountIn", 1)]
        public BigInteger AmountIn { get; set; }

        [Parameter("address[]", "path", 2)]
        public List<string> Path { get; set; }
    }

    [Function("decimals", "uint256")]
    public class DecimalsFunction : FunctionMessage
    {
    }
    [FunctionOutput]
    public class AmountsOutDTO : IFunctionOutputDTO
    {
        [Parameter("uint256[]", "amounts", 1)]
        public List<BigInteger> Amounts { get; set; }
    }
```